# How do I ask google to purge / reindex / flush their cache of a URL I do NOT control?

Tags: google-search, google-cache

How do I ask google to purge / reindex / flush their cache of a URL I do NOT control?

I am helping out a busy, important webmaster who has corrected an error in the content in a vital PDF.  I noticed that the error was still in [google's cached version](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwitnJLs4L_tAhWRHjQIHaUbB2EQIDABegQIARAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3AeTmD6uPjFocJ%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcovid19criticalcare.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F11%2FFLCCC-Ivermectin-in-the-prophylaxis-and-treatment-of-COVID-19.pdf%2B%26cd%3D2%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dus%26client%3Dsafari&usg=AOvVaw250sYOggYzaDlxhMPkFoT8). I googled *purge google cache*.  I logged into the renamed webmaster central and couldn't find a solution.  I searched its help system for *purge, flush*, and *reindex*, to no avail.  The documentation [indicates](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289#request_indexing) the Request Reindexing tool had been disabled for two months and would only work for URLs at domains I do control anyway.

Comment: (note: I've answered my own question and explained myself in it.)

Comment: If you are helping the webmaster, you could have them use a tool in Google Search Console or even grant you access to Google Search Console.

Comment: True in general. In this case, I had limited info and knew almost nothing about the webmaster, such as if they had Google Search Console set up, or their level of expertise. I was being a good Samaritan.

Answer (score 2):

An answer, documented [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7041154) is to use Google's "Remove Outdated Content" tool/page.  To do so, it's best to go to that page to read up on what it is and isn't good for, and alternatives.

The question was:

> How do I ask google to purge / reindex / flush their cache of a URL I do NOT control?

Perhaps the terms I was using to describe the problem were hampering me.
I knew there was (i.e. had been) a way to do this as I recall I'd used it before and the question is certainly a FAQ but I wasn't finding an answer, though I'm sure there are many out there.  Eventually I did, but I thought I'd put this Q&A here to help the next person in this position.